# Advanced USE >= AND <= in SQL

Tags: sql

Don't know how to call the question title.

I need to shows result base on WHERE DOCDATE >= (From my DateADD function ) and DOCDATE <= (From my DateADD function )

My Dateadd fuction pulling a list  of last 52 week's date from today's date.

Error message is sub-query returned more than 1 Value

```
`DECLARE @NOW Date
SET @NOW =GetDate()
SELECT        TOP (1) ItemCode, Dscription, Price, DocDate
FROM            dbo.PCH1
WHERE       ItemCode = '3255' AND (DocDate In  ( SELECT DATEADD(Week,  - WEEKS.n, @NOW) as Date
FROM            (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30), (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36), (37), (38), (39), (40), (41), (42), 
                         (43), (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49), (50), (51)) WEEKS(n)))
`
```

Hard coded version is bit messy and i don't want to do union all 20 time

```
    SELECT        TOP (4) ItemCode, Price, DocDate
FROM            dbo.PCH1
WHERE        (ItemCode = N'3255') AND (DocDate <= DATEADD(Week, - 48, GETDATE())) AND (DocDate >= DATEADD(Week, - 52, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: looks like a good opportunity to use `GROUP BY week`

Comment: This is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2012